# How to create array of object instances in vala

Tags: arrays, pointers, vala

as I was trying to nail down the bug why my [gtk4_list_clocks](https://github.com/aeldemery/gtk4_list_clocks) only ever update one of the clocks and not all of them, I've traced down the problem to be in `GLib.SList.prepend()`.
Changing from `GLib.SList` to `Gee.ArrayList` didn't solve the problem.
In the [c code example](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/listview_clocks.c#L283) a list of all clock widgets were created by appending them to a singly linked list. I've tried to mimic that but as it turned out the list size is always 1 and only one object ever get appended.

```
/* This is the list of all the ticking clocks */
static Gee.ArrayList<Clock> ticking_clocks = null;
// ...
construct {
        ticking_clocks = new Gee.ArrayList<Clock> ();
    }
void start_ticking () {
        /* if no clock is ticking yet, start */
        if (ticking_clock_id == 0) {
            ticking_clock_id = GLib.Timeout.add_seconds (1, tick);
        }
        ticking_clocks.add (this); // Bug
        // Although instance pointer is different according to the number of instantiated objects!!!
        print ("Clock instance %p\n", this); 
        // always 1 !!!
        print ("Number of ticking clocks %d\n", ticking_clocks.size);
    }
```

Could somebody please help to point out the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```cs
void main () {
    var a = new SList<Clock> ();
    a.append (new Clock ());
    a.append (new Clock ());
    a.append (new Clock ());
    a.append (new Clock ());
    a.append (new Clock ());
    print (@"Array length is $(a.length())\n");
}

class Clock {}
```

I'm not sure what the problem would be in your code, but I would remove the `static` from the `ticking_clocks` field. It can also be initialised with:

```cs
private Gee.ArrayList<Clock> ticking_clocks = new Gee.ArrayList<Clock> ();
```

I would also move the ticker outside the instance. If your `SourceFunc` returns `Source.CONTINUE` it will carry on ticking. Here is a stripped back example using `MainContext`. `MainContext` is the event loop within GLib's `MainLoop`, `GApplication`, etc. It is useful to understand to get a good grasp of Vala's `async` functions/methods:

```cs
void main () {
    var maincontext = MainContext.default();
    var time_to_quit = false;
    var count = 5;
    SourceFunc quit = () => {
        print (@"$count\n");
        count --;
        var result = Source.CONTINUE;
        if (count < 1) {
            time_to_quit = true;
            result = Source.REMOVE;
            }
        return result;
    };
    Timeout.add_seconds (1, (owned)quit);
    while (time_to_quit == false) {
        maincontext.iteration( true );
        }
}
```

Be aware the `Timeout` is not precise, it is at least a second. So you may want to increase the frequency and then check the time when you update the clock.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information. 
Actually I was able to solve the apparent problem with the help from the folks at gnome discourse.
By adding intialization of the list inside a `static construct`
But I have really benefited from your explanation. Thanks